# Change home directory in OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

After upgrading to OS X Mavericks, when I open terminal I get the following error.

No home directory: /home/(my-user-name)

I can navigate to /Users/(my-user-name) to access my files but I have to do it every time I open terminal. This also affects my projects which access home directory because the path is wrong.

Can anyone tell me how to change the home directory to /Users/(my-user-name)?

Comment: Do you have Terminal preferences to run a specific command on open of a new terminal window?

Comment: What about a `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` or a `.profile`?

Comment: They are present inside /Users/... the command 'cd ~' changes path to '/'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a programming question and is better off on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: This has been answered in super user: http://superuser.com/questions/154193/setting-a-users-home-directory-on-mac-os-x-server-from-the-command-line

Comment: Looks like [this Stack Exchange][1] answer may help as well.


  [1]: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51280/where-do-i-find-my-user-folder-in-the-os-x-folder-hierarchy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

User records on OS X are stored in a "Open Directory" database. To modify the home directory for a user, you can either

- open the "Directory Utility" app with

  ```
    open "/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app"
    # On older macOS Versions:
    open "/System/Library/CoreServices/Directory Utility.app"
  ```
- select the "Directory Editor" tab,
- choose "Viewing: Users" in the pop-up,
- select your user,
- edit the "NFSHomeDirectory" entry,
- save.

Or, from the command line (as superuser):

```
# dscl . -change Users/USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory OLDHOMEDIR NEWHOMEDIR
```

In any case: be careful! A wrong edit in the user Open Directory database might make
your system unusable.

Comment: In `10.14.6 ` path is `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory\ Utility.app`

Comment: @JonathanCross: Thank you, I have added that information.